# Android Table Layout add button programmatically

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am using reflection on my project. And I am adding a button dynamically of fields.
But I need orders for add button. 3 button per line.

How can I do this in code?
Like this:

[image: image description]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pZzOW.jpg

Comment: I would suggest you to simply apply grid view and gridAdapter for that, when you already added to the list, simply call notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: can you help for code? ı am begginner